# Jenkins Job to run SOQL query

Tags: jenkins, migration, salesforce, soql, sfdx

I'm trying to get a Jenkins job to run sfdx force:data:soql:query commands in order to migrate configuration data sets between our production org and our sandboxes after a refresh. Certain configurations do not persist on a refresh so we need a way to move that data.

Running the queries from the command line on the Jenkins server work as expected, however the job when it runs fails with the following error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

The job does three things:
Authorizes to the DevHub, lists out the connected orgs, and then performs a SQOL query to just print some data - 16 lines to be exact. Here are the commands in the shell script of the job:

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} -u ${DEV_HUB} -f ${JENKINS_HOME}/certs/prod/server.key -r [...] -a DevHub
sfdx force:org:list
sfdx force:data:soql:query -u ${DEV_HUB} -q "SELECT Id, Name FROM [...tablename...]" -r human
```

I am completely stumped on why this is happening. Again, running the SOQL command directly on the server through PowerShell or Command Line works as expected. I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one stumped me for a long time but we finally got it figured out.

If you are seeing this error, make sure to check your machine's environmental variables. I saw a TON of other answers pointing to this as the issue where the install of SFDX path name had spaces in it as in C:|P:rogram Files\SFDX\bin but only showed some weird command line FOR loop that made no sense what so ever.

What we did was to completely uninstall all of SFDX making sure none of it was left on the machine and reinstalled into a folder we made where there was no spaces in the path name.

Once we did that, our job worked like it was supposed to. I hope this helps others who run into this same issue.